# If $V$ is a vector subspace of $R^n$, prove that $V^ \bot$ is a vector subspace of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a subspace of $R^n$. Let $V^ \bot$ be a subset of $R^n$ defined by:

$V ^ \bot$ = {$\vec x \in R^n$: $\vec x * \vec v = 0$ for all $\vec v \in V$}

Prove that $V^ \bot$ is a subspace of $R^n$

I really have no idea about it. Can anyone help please?

Or can I just show that:

$\vec 0$ $\in V^\bot$ since every $\vec x * 0 =0$ ;
and then take $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. Let $\vec x + \vec y$ we have the sum of $0$ again which satisfies. Last we take $c \in R$, $\vec x \in V^\bot$ then $c \vec x is 0$ therefore $V^\bot$ is a subspace of $R^n$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! When asking a question, it is useful to include information such as what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. This will generate better and more useful feedback from other users, more appropriate for whatever level you may be at.

Comment: Is the sum of two elements $\vec{x}, \vec{y}\in V^perp$ again in $V^\perp$? Is a multiple of a vector in $V^\perp$ still belong to $V^\perp$? So is $V^\perp$ a vector space itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to prove that a nonempty set $U$ of a vector space $V$ is to use the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). The test says that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if for every $u,v\in U$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ we have $u+\lambda v\in U$.

In our case we know $V^\perp\neq\varnothing$ since $\vec 0\in V^\perp$.

Now, let $x,y\in V^\perp$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. To show that $x+\lambda y\in V^\perp$ we must show that 
$$
(x+\lambda y)\cdot v=0\tag{1}
$$
for every $v\in V$.

To prove (1), note that
$$
(x+\lambda y)\cdot v
= x\cdot v+\lambda(y\cdot v)
= 0+\lambda(0)
= 0+0
= 0
$$

Comment: So should I take everything out from the bracket? Since x * v = 0 which is given, how do I know $\lambda y * v$is $0$ sir? Or can I just consider $(x+\lambda y)$ is s sum of $x$, which is in $V$ and the linear combination of $y$, but how is that going to give me zero?

Comment: I updated with a proof of the formula.

Comment: Whoops, how come I did not even think about that. lol Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A is a subspace of a vector space W over a field F if

(i) $u+v \in A, \, \forall u, v \in A $

(ii)  $a u \in A, \forall a \in F, u\in A $

Comment: We usually also enforce $0 \in A$ so that the empty set is not considered as a subspace vacuously